# Cannot connect to my Flask Web service, with Azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, flask, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run the simpliest 'hello.py' Flask app on my Azure VM who's running on Ubuntu.
This is the code :

> ```
> from flask import Flask
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
>
> @app.route("/")
> def get_data():
>         return 'Hello World'
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>         app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000)
> ```

But when I enter the 127.0.0.1:5000 on my browser, i have a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I already tried to remove my firewall, add a AllowAnyCustomInbound5000 on my Networking options in Azure...

Please help me !

Thank you

....................

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Try to connect SSH VM instance:

```
ssh user@host
```

And install dependencies

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev nginx
```

[image]

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
mkdir myFlaskApp && cd myFlaskApp
```

[image]

Create virtualenv and try to activate like below:

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

[image]

```
pip3 install flask gunicorn
```

[image]

Then, Create a simple flask web application like below:

```
vim app.py
```

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return "Hello world!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,hosts='0.0.0.0')
```

Then try to run `python app.py` or

```
$ FLASK_APP=app.py
$ flask run
```

Try to access to application from browser with 5000 like below:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

[image]

Then I run `python app.py` or

```
$ FLASK_APP=app.py
$ flask run
```

[image]

I got result successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Python Flask web application in azure linux | Krishan’s Tech Blog (krishansubudhi.github.io)](https://krishansubudhi.github.io/webapp/2018/12/01/flaskwebapp.html) by *krishnsubudhi*

[What is **name** in Flask: Let's Learn Python Together - CODEFATHER](https://codefather.tech/blog/python-__name__-flask/) by *Claudio Sabato*